# SQL MySQL IN operator with expression not column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this in MySQL

```
Id| name | types |
1 | John | 1,3   |
2 | Lena | 1     |
3 | Mika |4,6,5 .|
```

Where 'Types' is a list of numbers (its a derived varchar column).

Now how do I select records with specific types 1 or 2 or 3...
This did not work as expected:

`Select * from table where '1' IN (Types)`

It only returns records with only type '1' (so only 2nd row in example)
but I want to return all records that have '1' in Types (so  records 1 and 2 in example) nevermind
they have some other value in list also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!  Do not store numbers as strings!  You want a separate table with one row per "name" and per "type", a `name_types` table.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  If so, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
Select *
from table
where find_in_set('1', Types)
```